# upgrading from iphone beta to full 3.0

Tags: iphone, upgrade, beta-testing

So I have been developing against the iphone 3.0 beta's and have just gone to upgrade to the final version released this week.

however in itunes it says that i am currently using the latest version.

any iphone developers out there know how do you upgrade to final version of 3.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the direct download link for the new 3.0 ipsw:

http://appldnld.apple.com.edgesuite.net/content.info.apple.com/iPhone/061-6578.20090617.VfgtU/iPhone1,2_3.0_7A341_Restore.ipsw

Notice the 7A341 at the end. It's the same version number as what you see in the Settings -> General -> About

Answer (score 1):

I found that if I restored a 3.0GM device iTunes downloaded and installed the latest OS.

Answer (score 1):

Grab the file that nevan pointed to at - http://appldnld.apple.com.edgesuite.net/content.info.apple.com/iPhone/061-6578.20090617.VfgtU/iPhone1,2_3.0_7A341_Restore.ipsw

Plug your iPhone into iTunes, hold down the Option Key, if using a Mac and click the Restore button from iTunes. If you're using Windows I believe it's the ALT button. From here you'll get a file dialog where you can point to the IPSW file.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the GM seed last week and this should be the latest version  - but like you I can't find any images for 3.0. As iTunes sees the version as the latest I think it can be assumed that the GM seed version is the latest.

It worries me a little that you get the same answer from iTunes when using a beta version - perhaps my assumption is not correct.

I guess that we will get the software images at some point - for sure we also need 2.x images available so that we can revert to these configurations.

UPDATE: I confirmed that the GM matches the final version same build number etc (7A341) - if you didn't get that you'll have to get the update from iTunes. If you have an iPod then you will have to pay for an update or wait for the image to added to the dev site.

Answer (score 0):

The 3.0GM version is exactly the same as the version released through iTunes - there is no difference, even the build number is the same (3.0GM shows 7A341 in Settings > General > About, 3.0 official shows 7A341 also).